# How to properly restore an FMX form?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Minimizing an FMX form with the menu bar button and then restoring by clicking on the task bar icon will bring the form back to the foreground, but will not activate the window. The form is also minimized "directly" rather applying the animation that "shrinks" the window to the taskbar. The forms OnActivate event is not fired.

Curiously, if I patch the WindowProc and call ShowWindow with SW_RESTORE upon deactivation the form will get restored properly after clicking the taskbar icon. I'm not sure why. The minimize animation still does not get fired though.

```
procedure TForm1.WindowProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  case Msg.Msg of
    WM_ACTIVATE: if (Msg.WParamLo = WA_INACTIVE) then ShowWindow(WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle).Wnd, SW_RESTORE);
  end;
  Msg.Result := CallWindowProc(OrgWndProc, WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle).Wnd, Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam);
end;
```

I can observe this behavior with a blank FMX HD form on Windows 8. This seems like an obvious bug to me, is there a better way to work around it ?

Comment: What version of FMX?

Comment: It's XE5 update 2 if that's what you mean, I'm not aware of distinct versioning for FMX.

Comment: Agreed, thats what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got around this by modifying the *FMX.Platform.Win.pas* file. In the **TPlatformWin.CreateAppHandle** method you need to comment (or remove) those lines:

```
FApplicationHWND := CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE or WS_EX_APPWINDOW, FMAppClass.lpszClassName,
  PChar(LApplicationTitle), WS_POPUP or WS_GROUP, 0, 0, 0, 0, GetDesktopWindow, 0, HInstance, nil);
Winapi.Windows.ShowWindow(FApplicationHWND, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

I think that solution came from the Embarcadero Discussion Forums. The message is gone, but I give you the link anyway in case it comes back: https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?messageID=556541&#556541

Comment: Don't make the desktop window be the owner. Pass 0 instead. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Guess somebody should tell Embarcadero about that ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
procedure Tmainform.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Single);
var
h:thandle;
  begin
  h:=FmxHandleToHWND(Handle);
      if getforegroundwindow <> h then
      begin
        SetForeGroundWindow(h);
        BringWindowToTop(h);
        SetCursorPos(Left + round(X), Top + round(Y));
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
end;
```

Comment: setfocus(h); before end; is least an option to get control of keystrokes or mouseevents on application level, f.e, if mousemove event is triggert on another panel (object) thats is created inside the mainform.