# FMX form doesn't minimize by taskbar click; animation doesnt work

Tags: windows, delphi, firemonkey

There are 2, or even 3 question:

1) When I click the application's taskbar icon, the form doesn't minize unlike a VCL application
Digging into FMX.Platform.Win WndProc I found these lines probably causing the issue (as I understand this code cause the app to restore back immediatelly as I minimize it)

```
WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
  begin
    Result := DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    if BOOL(wParam) then
      PlatformWin.RestoreApp;
   end;
```

2) When I click form's minimize button, sometimes the form minimezes to desktop:

[image] 
patching

```
 procedure TPlatformWin.MinimizeApp;
   {...}
   Application.MainForm.WindowState := TWindowState.wsMinimized;
```

seems solves the issue

3) The issue from this question [How to properly restore an FMX form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313956/how-to-properly-restore-an-fmx-form) is still actual in 10.2

Given answer to patch `TPlatformWin.CreateAppHandle` I dont understand: changing `GetDesktopWindow` to `0` doesn't change anything, deleting important code as that answer suggests seems pointless

Comment: This is "normal" up to 10.2.3. I don't have 10.3 yet, but if this persists an error report should be posted.

Comment: @Sherlock70 https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21809?filter=-4 If someone wanna vote

Comment: Upvoted your report. Lets hope it helps.